# Sql equivalence of MySql Connection String (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have an application in C# that connects to a MySql application, and it works great. I need to build the same thing for a Sql database, but I'm find how to build the same connection string.

Which would be the equivalence o this line? Does it remain the same?
Allow User Variables=True;respect binary flags=false; Connection Timeout=10; Pooling=false

Comment: Take a look at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: I can't find the equivalence of 'Allow User Variables' and 'Respect binary flags' :(

Comment: That's because there may not be an equivalent. Just because MySQL has these settings it doesn't mean that another database will.

Comment: Agreed, you should first check if SQL Server even has the same (or equivalent) features or concepts, before trying to find a connection string which allows you to set those values. I'm not aware personally that it does, in these specific cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Allow User Variables=true`: SQL Server has no need for this because it allows user variables by default.
- `Respect Binary Flags=false`: There is no equivalent for this in SQL Server. It makes Connector/NET treat some `BLOB` columns as `TEXT` which shouldn't be required if the column types are created correctly in the new DB.
- `Connection Timeout=10`: use `ConnectTimeout=10` or `Connection Timeout=10` for SqlClient.
- `Pooling=false`: Use `Pooling=false` for SqlClient.